# 5.0 event schedulers

Tags: mysql

Is there event scheduler in mysql 5.0, if not what is the closest way to achieve that?

I need to do data transfer from 1 table from source db to destination's db table based on some condition. (in an automated manner).

Also is there any way of implementing this without procedures/functions/triggers as my db has some restrictions over cloud setup.

Thanks,
Karthick

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one using `5.0` still

Answer (score 2):

MySQL 5.1 and later contain an event scheduler, there's no such feature in 5.0.

Perhaps you can use the scheduling mechanism of your OS as an alternative, like `cron` for example if your on Unix. When you building an application on top of MySQL then you might want to take a look at the scheduling mechanisms of your application platform (e.g. a framework like [Quartz](http://quartzscheduler.org) if your doing Java development). The latter is however more heavyweight than the MySQL event scheduler.